# While loop -- Count of len(Words) loops six time of the "flower" has six Letter

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

While count<len(word) loops six times because the word "Flower" has six letters. i then need to ask the user to guess again, and if the guess is incorrect , run that same loop again, and then ask for input again until the input is finally correct. how can i accomplish this? again, my goal: Run loop six time ask for input. incorrect  input restarts process...

```
word = 'flower'
print()
print('Hint : ')
count = 0
while count< len(word):
    print('_', end='')
    count += 1
print()
print()
attempts = 0 
guess = input(' what is your guess? ')
count=0
while len (guess) != len(word):
    guess = input('Please enter correct length of word : ')
    attempts += 1

while count < len(guess):
    if guess [count].lower() not in word:
        print('_', end='')
    elif guess [count].lower() == word[count]:
        print(guess[count].upper(),end='')
    else:
        print(guess[count].lower(),end='')
        count += 1
attempts += 1
print()
print(f'it took you {attempts} guesses.')
print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a program which asks user to guess a word for the length of the word number of times and if the users guesses it before then it would stop asking and print a congratulating message.

```
word = 'flower'

wordLength = len(word)

count = 0
while count <= wordLength-1:
    askUserInput = input("Guess the word: ")

    if askUserInput == word:
        print("Congratulations, you have guessed the correct word")
        break

    print("Wrong guess, please try again")

    count += 1

if count == wordLength:
    print("All chances have been finished to guess the word")
```

Here the while loop will keep running until it the **count** variable matches the length of the word and the guesses made by user is wrong. But before reaching its limit, if the user guesses the right word then the loop breaks and prints a Congratulation message. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired behavior of running the loop six times and asking the user to guess again if the input is incorrect, you can modify the code as follows:

```py
word = 'flower'
print()
print('Hint:')
count = 0
while count < len(word):
    print('_', end='')
    count += 1
print()
print()

attempts = 0 
guess = input('What is your guess? ')
count = 0
while len(guess) != len(word):
    guess = input('Please enter a word with the correct length: ')
    attempts += 1

while count < len(guess):
    if guess[count].lower() != word[count]:
        break
    count += 1

if count == len(word):
    print('Congratulations! Your guess is correct.')
else:
    print('Incorrect guess. Please try again.')

attempts += 1
print(f'It took you {attempts} guesses.')
print()
```

In this modified code:

After prompting the user for a guess, we check if the length of the guess matches the length of the word. If not, we repeatedly ask the user to enter a word with the correct length until a valid guess is provided. The `attempts` variable keeps track of the number of attempts.

Inside the loop that checks each character of the guess, we break out of the loop if any character in the guess is incorrect. If the loop completes without breaking, it means the entire guess matches the word, and we print a congratulatory message. Otherwise, we indicate an incorrect guess and prompt the user to try again.

Finally, we increment the `attempts` variable, which counts the total number of guesses made, and print the total number of attempts.

By using the `break` statement, the loop will restart from the beginning whenever an incorrect character is encountered in the guess, ensuring that the user gets another chance to enter the correct guess.

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?